# Access Geolocation on Safari for locally hosted website across local network

Tags: php, safari, geolocation, localhost, lan

I'm running a php site on a MacBook using the following code which uses geolocation.

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8888
```

I can access this using any of the follow on my MacBook using Safari

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888
http://localhost:8888
http://192.168.1.25:8888
```

However geolocation doesn't work on http://192.168.1.25:8888 and I get the following error in the console on Safari

```
[Error] [blocked] Access to geolocation was blocked over insecure connection to http://192.168.1.25:8888.
Error getting location:"Origin does not have permission to use Geolocation service"
```

I'm wanting to be able to access this on an iPad on my local network, which I can access using the below IP and port.

```
http://192.168.1.25:8888
```

However as this uses safari I am facing the same issue that geolocation is blocked.

From looking online I can see that Safari appears to block geolocation on what it deems are insecure sites. Is there any way I can get this to work locally?

Comment: It is already working "locally" - for 127.0.0.1 / localhost, which appear to be exceptions from the insecure connection restriction. But for addresses that are only in the local _network_, but not actually the same machine, it appears there is no such exception. If Safari offers no way to lift these restrictions via individual site settings - then you will probably have to find a way, to access this via HTTPS. If you can't get that set up locally, then perhaps use a service like `ngrok`.

Comment: What makes you think that this error message is in any way related to PHP or [tag:lan]?

Comment: @NicoHaase PHP - because I'm using the php command I the terminal to 'host' the site so could the issue be down to how I'm hosting it eg do I need to set different flags. lan - because I'm having issues over my local network due to haw safari is seeing the address